# Looking for a C program that can detect whether a sequence similar to the Collatz conjecture terminates or not

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm looking for a program in the C language that can:

- scan an unsigned number that can be as big as 10^14
- if it is even divide it by 2
- otherwise replace it with 3*n+3 (n being the number
  that is scanned) so that it becomes an even number
- do this as many
  times as needed to see if it is equal 1 at the end. If it is, print
  "yes", otherwise print "no".

The problem is that I don't know when to stop the operation and I'm not sure if any number other than 2^x can equal 1 at the end but I think I'm wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: @ user202729 i know but i don't know when to stop the cycle

Comment: So us the code so far and maybe we can help

Comment: You start from number n0, then generate n1, then generate n2, etc... If you store all the numbers as you go, and for every new number you check that you have not already produced that. If the number repeat itself, you have a cycle and you can stop.

Comment: @ Fabio it makes sense but i don't know how to do that. i tried but it got so messy

Comment: Angela - show us your attempt.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Anyway, as pointed out, it never gets into a cycle.

Comment: @user202729 it does get in cycle, for all numbers that are not powers of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that in the cycle finding process you could get some fairly big numbers that would overflow all built-in types of C.

Instead, you could solve the problem mathematically.  There is a much harder, similar problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture, but this one is easy. Consider that `3n + 3 = 3(n + 1)` - a multiple of 3. And a multiple of 3 cannot be a power of 2.

So, either the initial number is a power of 2 (then print "yes") or it can never become a power of 2 (print "no").

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t n;

    // get the input
    scanf("%" SCNu64, &n);

    // detect whether n is a power of 2
    while(n > 1) {
        if(n % 2 != 0) {
            printf("no\n"); // not a power of 2
            return 0;
        }
        n /= 2;
    }
    // is a power of 2
    printf("yes\n");
}
```

Comment: C has no inherent limits on how big numbers can be, nor even on how large a number it can represent.  Perhaps you mean that it does not have a built-in arbitrary-precision numeric type, but arbitrary-precision libraries are available, such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: ... implemented in C.  Using an external library for such a thing is a convenience, perhaps a big one, but it does not speak to the capabilities of the language.

Comment: Ok, point taken and edited. Perhaps calling it a bad language is subjective - it's just inconvenient when you have to use it for coding interviews, competitive programming, or study exercises as I assume the OP has.